# How to paste output of multiple commands

Tags: paste

I want to merge two unzipped files `f1` and `f2` in one command, like

```
paste (zcat f1.gz) (zcat f2.gz).
```

What is the right syntax?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post an example of the (uncompressed) input and output you expect; you can edit your question to add this information. As it stands, it's unclear to me how you want to "merge" the two files; is it with the actual command `paste`, or otherwise?

Comment: "I want to merge two unzipped files" --> zipped?

Answer (score 14):

almost there...

```
paste <(zcat f1.gz) <(zcat f2.gz)
```

Answer (score -1):

Great answer: Thanks a lot.

I've used it for pasting three columns, each one in a compressed file.

Just for sharing : source 3200 redhat machines, 250 millions of points aprox per day...

This is not exactly the way we get all the files locally but catch the idea ( we use `ansible` in the real task)

```bsh
for i in $(cat list_of_hostnames.txt)
do
 sadf -U -- -A <file from yesterday> | pigz -9 > host_date_file.tsv.gz
done
```

Asume we get all such files in the working directory:

```bsh
pigz -cd *.tsv.gz| sed -E 's/\t/\n/g' | split --numeric-suffixes=1 -nr/6 - kk.
```

After such command, you get six compressed files called `kk.01` to `kk.06` corresponding to hostmane, interval, timestamp in seconds from epoch, device, metric and value.

Just for saving space :

```bsh
rm kk.02
```

( I don't need interval having timestamps) and then

```bsh
pigz -9 kk.0[13456]
```

and now is when I use :

```bsh
paste <(zcat kk.05.gz ) <(zcat kk.01.gz) <(zcat kk.04.gz) <(zcat kk.06.gz) | grep '%idle' | pigz -9 > metric_host_device_value.tsv.gz
```